# python subprocess read stdout as it executes

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

one of my function in the program checks the md5sum of hashfile

```
def check():
    print "checking integrity status.."
    md5 = subprocess.Popen(["md5sum", "-c", hashfile],shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #fopen = open(basefile, "r")
    for f in md5.stdout.readlines():
        fc = f.rstrip("\n")
        sys.stdout.write("\rChecking..." + fc)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

now what happens is that the whole command is first executed and then for loop reads from md5 using md5.stdout.readlines, as such it is not dynamic i.e. i dont get the output as the command is executed....is there a way i can get the output while the command is in execution...

**fixed using glglgl's answer:**

```
def check():
    print "checking integrity status.."
    md5 = subprocess.Popen(["md5sum", "-c", hashfile],shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #fopen = open(basefile, "r")
    fc = "NULL"
    i = 0
    for f in iter(md5.stdout.readline, ''):
        k = fc
        fc = f.rstrip("\n")
        if "FAILED" in fc:
            print fc
        i = i + 1
        sys.stdout.write("\rChecking... "+ str(i)+ " " + fc + (' ' * (len(k) - len(fc))) )
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Related, but not an answer to the question itself: have a look at [hashlib.md5()](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib). Might be simpler?

Comment: i am using python 2.4.3 and hashlib is not available..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. There are several ways.

1. First, you could work with `md5.stdout.read()`, but there you would have to do line separation by yourself.
2. Then, you could operate with the file object `md5.stdout` as iterator. But there seems to be an issue with buffering, i. e. you don't get the results immediately.
3. And then there is a possibility to call `md5.stdout.readline()` repeatedly until it returns `''`.

The third way is to be preferred in this case; I would suggest it to do like this:

...

```
for f in iter(md5.stdout.readline, ''):
    fc = f.rstrip("\n")
    sys.stdout.write("\rChecked " + fc)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I have also changed the output text, as there is only an output if che check is done already.

If that is not what you want, but rather really haveing every output captured separately, you should switch to point 1. But that makes it more complicated. I will think about a solution on indication that it is wanted.

There, one must consider the following points:

- `read()` blocks, so one should read byte for byte (quite ugly).
- There is the question what should be output and when should there be a intermitting output.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster is correct that hashlib is not available in Python 2.4, however, the md5 library is available. Example workaround:

```
try:
        # Python 2.5 and up.
        import hashlib
        md5Hash = hashlib.md5

except ImportError:
        # Python 2.4 and below.
        import md5
        md5Hash = md5.new

somedata = 'foobar'
hashstring = md5Hash (somedata).hexdigest ()
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the file size?

Popen creates a new child process to run the command. Maybe it finishes before you run the for loop.

You can check if the "subprocess" has finished looking returncode attribute (in your code: md5.returncode)